# What's the mistake in "When I was a child, I must eat everything on my plate or I wouldn’t get any dessert."?

Tags: grammar

"When I was a child, I must eat everything on my plate or I wouldn’t get any dessert." Find a part of the sentence that contains a mistake.

Comment: This looks like a homework or assessment question which we do not answer. However I will give you a clue. Try comparing the tenses of the verbs.

Comment: As you should see from that earlier question, many perfectly competent native speakers really don't like using the degenerate verb "must" as a past tense. But *other* competent native speakers don't mind it - including Ralph Waldo Emerson, so we all have to accept it's at least "valid". In short, if you got this from a test, the test-setter doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: (I recall that until I actually looked into this and posted an answer on ELU nearly a decade ago, I had no idea that ***mote*** - as in arcane ceremonial *So mote it be!* - was actually the ***Present*** tense, and that originally ***must*** was a ***Past*** tense form only. Still fascinating, after all these years! :)